# Final form of parametric SQL commands in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, odbc

I am getting a syntax error when I send a parameterized query to Access from my C# program via ADO.NET.

I, of course, know what SQL string I have included in my code, with the parameter names embedded inside.

Does anyone know how I can look at the SQL string that is finally sent to the DBMS during after I call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`?

Thanks.

EDIT:

There is no way to see that string in the interactive debugger or in an Access log or something?
In order for anyone to reproduce my precise problem, they would have to have my database, which isn't going to happen.  However, since interest has been expressed in the details of what I'm trying to do I'm publishing the following code fragment:

```
  OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = 
     @"insert into Posts (Page, Line, TimeStamp, Status) values
           (@pagename, @lineno, @now, 'SAVED')";
  cmd.Connection = _cn;
  cmd.Transaction = transaction;
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@pagename",OdbcType.VarChar));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@lineno",OdbcType.VarChar));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@now",OdbcType.DateTime));
  cmd.Parameters["@pagename"].Value = pageId;
  cmd.Parameters["@lineno"].Value = lineId;
  cmd.Parameters["@now"].Value = now;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I hope it helps.

Thanks again.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that "TimeStamp" may be a reserved word in AccessSQL and this is likely the cause of the syntax error.  However, even assuming this is the cause, the general question of how to see the SQL query in its final form remains open.

Comment: You could also post the SQL here... And a question... does the ADO.NET provider for access really use parameter names in the SQL or just positional parameters (ie. question marks?)

Comment: To my surprise, TimeStamp *is* a reserved word: support.microsoft.com/kb/286335

Answer (score 1):

Access only uses positional parameters.

All you need to do is change your SQL to this:

```
insert into Posts (Page, Line, [TimeStamp], Status) values (?, ?, ?, 'SAVED')
```

making sure to put any additional parameters into the `Parameters` collection in the proper order.

**Edit:** Updated to solve the reserved-word issue.

**Edit:** It is not possible to trace the SQL that gets run on an OLE DB connection, at least not currently. See [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271649).

Comment: This works nicely, but is not a solution to the main question about seeing the SQL that arrive at Access.